# Exit segue Xcode 6.1.1 again not working

Tags: ios, segue, exit, xcode6.1, unwind-segue

I am aware that exit segues where broke in early xcode 6 betas and swift. I have Xcode 6.1.1 installed but i do not seem to get it to work.

I do have this function in my destination ViewController

```
@IBAction func unwindToViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

however when crtl-dragging a button in my startingViewController to the controllers exit icon nothing happens, xcode does not seem to find the function in the other viewcontroller. some got an idea? right clicking the exit icon give me the empty black field with not functions in it.

Comment: See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them

Comment: @Mike Taverne - your link is not helpful. The problem is Unwind Segues don't appear in the Exit icon